# How do I fix a program that runs properly on a local server, but does not run after deploying to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, chalice

I am relatively knew to programming, especially in regards to the problem I am facing in regards to running post requests through amazon web services and use of API requests.

I currently have a program written below.

```
from chalice import Chalice
import requests, json
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi
app = Chalice(app_name='tradingview-webhook-alerts')
API_KEY = 'API'
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET'
BASE_URL = "https://paper-api.alpaca.markets"
ORDERS_URL = "{}/v2/orders".format(BASE_URL)
HEADERS = {'APCA-API-KEY-ID': API_KEY, 'APCA-API-SECRET-KEY': SECRET_KEY}

@app.route('/GDX',methods=['POST'])
def GDX():
    request = app.current_request
    webhook_message = request.json_body
    
    p = 1-(webhook_message['close'] / webhook_message['high'])
    if p<.0175: #if the high price for the 15m candle is 3% higher than the close, thee excution will not occur
        data = {
        "symbol": webhook_message['ticker'], #want it to access whatever the payload message is, payload message I believe is what the alert from Trading_View will send
        "qty": 8,
        "side": "buy",
        "type": "limit",
        "limit_price": webhook_message['close'],
        "time_in_force": "gtc",
        "order_class": "bracket",
        #need to find out the average max profit per trade
        "take_profit": {
        "limit_price": webhook_message['close'] * 1.0085 #take 0.6%% profit
        },
        "stop_loss": {
            "stop_price": webhook_message['close'] * 0.95, #stop loss of 6%
            "limit_price": webhook_message['close'] * 0.93
        }
        }
        r = requests.post(ORDERS_URL, json=data, headers=HEADERS)   

        response = json.loads(r.content)
        print(response)
        print(p)

        return {
        'message': 'I bought the stock!',
        'webhook_message': webhook_message
        }
    else:
        return{
            'message': 'stock not purchased',
            'webhook_message': webhook_message
        }

@app.route('/buy_SLV',methods=['POST'])
def buy_stock():
    request = app.current_request
    webhook_message = request.json_body
    
    data = {
    "symbol": webhook_message['ticker'], #want it to access whatever the payload message is, payload message I believe is what the alert from Trading_View will send
    "qty": 4,
    "side": "buy",
    "type": "limit",
    "limit_price": webhook_message['close'],
    "time_in_force": "gtc",
    "order_class": "bracket",
    "take_profit": {
    "limit_price": webhook_message['close'] * 1.008 #take 1% profit
    },
    "stop_loss": {
        "stop_price": webhook_message['close'] * 0.95, #stop loss of 2%
        "limit_price": webhook_message['close'] * 0.94
    }
}

    r = requests.post(ORDERS_URL, json=data, headers=HEADERS)   

    response = json.loads(r.content)
    print(response)
    print(response.keys())

    return {
        'message': 'I bought the stock!',
        'webhook_message': webhook_message
    }

@app.route('/GDX_UpperBB',methods=['POST'])
def GDX_UpperBB():
    request = app.current_request
    webhook_message = request.json_body

    api = tradeapi.REST(API_KEY, SECRET_KEY, base_url=BASE_URL)
    ids = []

    orders = api.list_orders(
    limit=100,
    nested=True  # show nested multi-leg orders
    )
    
    GDX_orders = [o for o in orders if o.symbol == 'GDX']
    for i in GDX_orders:
        ids.append(i.id)
        if len(orders)>0:
            print(ids)
            for i in ids:
                api.cancel_order(i)
        else:
            print('there are no orders')

    return{
        'message': 'I bought the stock!',
        'webhook_message': webhook_message
    }
```

the first two methods have been running fine (both through AWS and on local server). The third method (GDX_UpperBB) is what causes everything to stop working. When I run the program on a local server and make a call to the GDX_UpperBB method, it executes without issue. but when I deploy the program through the amazon web service API through chalice, I get a 502 BadGateway response with a `"message": "Internal server error"` throwback.

When I go into AWS and test the method this is the console response that I get (I removed about the first half of the response because it was long and everything said it ran successfully)

```
Mon Oct 26 00:46:51 UTC 2020 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 15 ms
Mon Oct 26 00:46:51 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Mon, 26 Oct 2020 00:46:51 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=127, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=621b56f9-6bee-43af-8fe2-7f2cbeb7420e, X-Amz-Function-Error=Unhandled, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5f961c7b-0a211c4e04be837554d0857f;sampled=0}
Mon Oct 26 00:46:51 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'alpaca_trade_api'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
Mon Oct 26 00:46:51 UTC 2020 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'alpaca_trade_api'. Lambda request id: 621b56f9-6bee-43af-8fe2-7f2cbeb7420e
Mon Oct 26 00:46:51 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
```

all help is appreciated.

Comment: The error says that you are missing some dependencies: No module named 'alpaca_trade_api'

Comment: so where should this be installed / added to the program above? It runs properly on a local host so im just confused where I should be troubleshooting this issue

Comment: You should bundle all dependencies with your lambda deployment package or provide them through a lambda layer.

Comment: Note that this code would have failed similarly on your local machine, had you not previously explicitly pip installed alpaca_trade_api.

Comment: @StephenMarkos Did it work when you added the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add the dependency to your requirements.txt filer or add the code to a vendor directory off your main project directory